# Nhibernate SQL named queries and projection

Tags: nhibernate, orm, projection

I've mapped a class to a SQL Server table and use an SQL named query to retrieve some rows from it. Also I don't want all of the columns on certain pages (e.g. if it's a document, I want to display its full content on a "View Details" page only, while its title can be on a list and the "View Details" page.

If I don't select all of the columns of the table in question, I get an IndexOutOfRangeException on the columns that I've left out.

Is there a way to project only the columns I'm interested in on named queries or do I have to create extra POCOs for the different scopes of the application?

Regards,
F.

Comment: Your table definition and projection query would help in answering this question. BTW - Any reason that you're using a SQL query rather than HQL, Criteria, LINQ, etc.? SQL queries are only meant for edge cases where other query mechanisms cannot generate optimal SQL.

Comment: I need to retrieve the first X rows from a table with columns such as DocumentTitle, Text, PublishDate, AddDate, EditDate, Caption, AuditedBy. On a list page I only want to show the DocumentTitle and PublishDate. It has an XML mapping to a C# class and as long as I pull all of the columns in the query it works fine.

Comment: Since I'm new to NHibernate and there will be plenty of queries in the web app we're building, I much prefer to stick to SQL rather than check the log files to see what sort of SQL is being generated and how efficient it is. Criteria has a good API and provides an OO way to query data and I might end up using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [**NHibernate ad-hoc mapping**](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/06/29/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+LosTechies+%28LosTechies%29).

P.S.: Like the others have said, you should at least take a look at [**HQL**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html), [**Criteria**](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/19/nhibernate-queries-examples.aspx) or [**NHibernate.Linq**](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/8/17/linq-for-nhibernate-examples/). And to easily handle the generated SQL, everyone uses the [**NHibernate Profiler**](http://nhprof.com/).

Comment: Criteria will do nicely in this instance.